Adapting CMA-ES library function for more parameters
I am trying to use CMA-ES function from ensmallen library but don't know how to proceed in my case.
Here are the standard constructors for this function:

CMAES<SelectionPolicyType, TransformationPolicyType>()

CMAES<SelectionPolicyType, TransformationPolicyType>(lambda, transformationPolicy)

CMAES<SelectionPolicyType, TransformationPolicyType>(lambda, transformationPolicy, batchSize)

CMAES<SelectionPolicyType, TransformationPolicyType>(lambda, transformationPolicy, batchSize, maxIterations, tolerance, selectionPolicy)

CMAES<SelectionPolicyType, TransformationPolicyType>(lambda, transformationPolicy, batchSize, maxIterations, tolerance, selectionPolicy, stepSize)


And here is the function to optimize ():
double Evaluate(vec var, int T, int N, int K, mat X, double l, double C, double L, mat D) {

       /*Does something*/

        return y;
    }

So it requires much more additional arguments, than I could fit with CMAES function from ensmallen.
I don't understand if there is a way to use this library and this function in my case, when I need additional parameters to evaluate my function. I am very new to this and would appreciate help!
